# Sensing AC voltage

Tags: voltage, power-factor-correction, sensing

In a project I'm working on (Totem pole PFC) I need to sense the input AC voltage, scale it down, rectifing it/adding an offset and then send to the ADC of the digital controller to use in the control loop (average current control)

I tried a number of circuit, such as a voltage sensing transucer ([LEM LV-25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACYpg.png)), but it has 3 problems:it's expensive, it's slow (<10kHz BW) and it has accuracy problems as the large power resistors heat up.

So I thought about using a differential amplifier and detect the line voltage between L and N, set ground to half ADC reference, i.e. 1.25V and have the output voltage equals 1.25 + k Vac, where k is the differential amp gain

This circuit :

[image]

Is this circuit going to work properly? how can I add isolation? and for the ground for (V-) and 1.25V voltage reference, will it be the GND of the MCU or the totem pole? sorry for the silly questions.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you considered using one of the various linear optocouplers like HCNR200?

Comment: Just note that this differential amplifier does give you much common mode range

Comment: What amplitude are you expecting L and N to be?

Comment: I'm expecting the max rms value to be Vac=260Vrms max

Comment: You can add isolation using a simple low power low frequency transformer and convert your mains voltage to something like 12Vac or similar. A transformer with power about 1W could be found on the market and it will be enough. I think its accuracy will be much higher than any linear optocoupler you may find. May be a dummy laod resistor will be needed on the secondary.